# CryptoJS - Decrypt an encrypted file

Tags: javascript, file, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to write an application to do end-to-end encryption for files with JS in browser. However I don't seem to be able to get all files decrypted correctly.

**TL;DR** As it's impractical to encrypt files bigger than 1MB as a whole, I'm trying to encrypt them chunk by chunk. After doing so I try to write the encrypted words (resulted from `CryptoJS`'s WordArray) into a blob. As for decryption I read the files and split them to chunks according to map generated while encrypting the chunks and try to decrypt them. The problem is decrypted result is 0 bits!

I guess I'm not reading the chunks while decrypting correctly. Please take a look at the code below for the function `getBlob` (writing data to the blob) and the last part of `decryptFile` for reading chunks.

**More explanation**

I'm using CryptoJS AES with default settings.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
function encryptFile (file, options, resolve, reject) {
  if (!options.encrypt) {
    return resolve(file)
  }
  if (!options.processor || !options.context) {
    return reject('No encryption method.')
  }

  function encryptBlob (file, optStart, optEnd) {
    const start = optStart || 0
    let stop = optEnd || CHUNK_SIZE
    if (stop > file.size - 1) {
      stop = file.size
    }

    const blob = file.slice(start, stop)
    const fileReader = new FileReader()

    fileReader.onloadend = function () {
      if (this.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) return

      const index = Math.ceil(optStart / CHUNK_SIZE)
      const result = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(this.result)
      encryptedFile[index] = encrypt(result)

      chunksResolved++
      if (chunksResolved === count) {
        const {sigBytes, sigBytesMap, words} = getCipherInfo(encryptedFile)
        const blob = getBlob(sigBytes, words)

        resolve(blob, Object.keys(sigBytesMap))
      }
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  }

  let chunksResolved = 0
  const encryptedFile = []
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024
  const count = Math.ceil(file.size / CHUNK_SIZE)
  const encrypt = value => options.processor.call(
    options.context, value, 'file',
    (v, k) => CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(v, k))

  for (let start = 0; (start + CHUNK_SIZE) / CHUNK_SIZE <= count; start+= CHUNK_SIZE) {
    encryptBlob(file, start, start + CHUNK_SIZE - 1)
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to read the file chunk by chunk (each chunk is 1MB or `fileSize % 1MB`) as ArrayBuffer, converting it to WordArray for CryptoJS to understand and encrypt it.

After encrypting all the chunks I try to write each word they have to a blob (using a code I found in CryptoJS's issues in Google Code, mentioned below) and **I guess here is what goes wrong**. I also generated a map for where encrypted chunks end so I can later use it to get the chunks out of the binary file for decryption.

And here's how I decrypt the files:

```
function decryptFile (file, sigBytesMap, filename, options, resolve, reject) {
  if (!options.decrypt) {
    return resolve(file)
  }
  if (!options.processor || !options.context) {
    return reject('No decryption method.')
  }

  function decryptBlob (file, index, start, stop) {
    const blob = file.slice(start, stop)
    const fileReader = new FileReader()

    fileReader.onloadend = function () {
      if (this.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) return

      const result = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(this.result)
      decryptedFile[index] = decrypt(result)

      chunksResolved++
      if (chunksResolved === count) {
        const {sigBytes, words} = getCipherInfo(decryptedFile)
        const finalFile = getBlob(sigBytes, words)

        resolve(finalFile, filename)
      }
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  }

  let chunksResolved = 0
  const count = sigBytesMap.length
  const decryptedFile = []
  const decrypt = value => options.processor.call(
    options.context, value, 'file',
    (v, k) => CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(v, k))

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    decryptBlob(file, i, parseInt(sigBytesMap[i - 1]) || 0, parseInt(sigBytesMap[i]) - 1)
  }
}
```

Decryption is exactly like the encryption but doesn't work. Although chunks are not 1MB anymore, they are limited to sigBytes mentioned in the map. There is no result for the decryption! `sigBytes: 0`.

Here's the code for generating a blob and getting sigbytesMap:

```
function getCipherInfo (ciphers) {
  const sigBytesMap = []
  const sigBytes = ciphers.reduce((tmp, cipher) => {
    tmp += cipher.sigBytes || cipher.ciphertext.sigBytes
    sigBytesMap.push(tmp)
    return tmp
  }, 0)

  const words = ciphers.reduce((tmp, cipher) => {
    return tmp.concat(cipher.words || cipher.ciphertext.words)
  }, [])

  return {sigBytes, sigBytesMap, words}
}

function getBlob (sigBytes, words) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(sigBytes)
  for (var i = 0; i < sigBytes; i++) {
    const byte = (words[i >>> 2] >>> (24 - (i % 4) * 8)) & 0xff
    bytes[i] = byte
  }

  return new Blob([ new Uint8Array(bytes) ])
}
```

I'm guessing the issue is the method I'm using to read the encrypted chunks. Or maybe writing them!

I should also mention that previously I was doing something different for encryption. I was stringifying each WordArray I got as the result for `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` using the `toString` method with the default encoding (which I believe is `CryptoJS.enc.Hex`) but some files didn't decrypt correctly. It didn't have anything to do with the size of the original file, rather than their types. Again, I'm guessing!

Comment: 1) Why are you doing this? 2) Do you know that's insecure? What exactly are you achieving with this encryption? Since it's browser to browser - key will be visible, so what's the point?

Comment: Is `k` hard coded or is it retrieved through asymmetric crypto?

Comment: @Mjh To achieve zero-knowledge-encryption, so we wouldn't have access to user's data.

Comment: @LukePark I'm using a random key encrypted using RSA encryption method.

Comment: If you have the key, you have the knowledge about data. Since you have the key, this zero-knowledge principle is broken. What's wrong with SSL/TLS?

Comment: @Mjh That's not the problem right now. We're working around that using pub/priv keys, encrypting public key with user's password and not storing their password through SRP (secure remote password). We don't have access to users' data since their data is encrypted with a key encrypted with user's public key and private key is already encrypted and out of our sight.

Comment: Right, what are you encrypting the data with? User's public key? Public key encryption has a limit to how much data it can encrypt. The whole premise of your system sounds completely off - you have a file whose contents you can **see**. If you couldn't see the contents, you'd have no need to encrypt it. You could just deliver the mangled blob to the other person, who would decrypt it by asking the key from the owner. You have too many bad decisions here and if I knew exactly which service you were providing, I would never sign up for it. No hard feelings, there's too much of "wrong" here.

Comment: @Mjh As I said, data is encrypted with a key which is encrypted with user's public key. We allow people to join in teams, while doing so would have access to the key, decrypted in the process allowed by the original member of the team. All in all, the entire process enables zero-knowledge encryption. There is no visibility of data on our side. I'd really enjoy discussing the issue of privacy another time. But right now I need some workaround for the issue and all these comments arr unhelpful for others, if any, trying to get more info on the matter.

Comment: @Mjh As for the file issue, as you can see in the code, I'm trying to encrypt the entire data using the AES method and after doing so, I'll send the file to the server. So the only person who can see the contents is the person uploading the file. If the client is contaminated there isn't much we can do, as we wouldn't be able to do anything if there was no end-to-end encryption. The issue here is how to encrypt the file as it is practically impossible to encrypt it as a whole in the browser. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the `WordArray` returned by `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key)` has 4 extra words as padding which should not be included in the final result. CryptoJS tries unpadding the result but only changes `sigBytes` accordingly and doesn't change `words`. So when decrypting, before writing chunks to file pop those extra words. 4 words for full chunks and 3 for smaller ones (last chunk).

Answer (score 0):

[check this issue](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/421)

```js
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

async function encryptBlobToBlob(blob: Blob, secret: string): Promise<Blob> {
    const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(await blob.arrayBuffer());
    const result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, secret);
    return new Blob([result.toString()]);
}
export async function decryptBlobToBlob(blob: Blob, secret: string): Promise<Blob> {
    const decryptedRaw = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(await blob.text(), secret);
    return new Blob([wordArrayToByteArray(decryptedRaw)]);
}

function wordToByteArray(word, length) {
    const ba = [];
    const xFF = 0xff;
    if (length > 0) ba.push(word >>> 24);
    if (length > 1) ba.push((word >>> 16) & xFF);
    if (length > 2) ba.push((word >>> 8) & xFF);
    if (length > 3) ba.push(word & xFF);

    return ba;
}

function wordArrayToByteArray({ words, sigBytes }: { sigBytes: number; words: number[] }) {
    const result = [];
    let bytes;
    let i = 0;
    while (sigBytes > 0) {
        bytes = wordToByteArray(words[i], Math.min(4, sigBytes));
        sigBytes -= bytes.length;
        result.push(bytes);
        i++;
    }
    return new Uint8Array(result.flat());
}

async function main() {
    const secret = "bbbb";
    const blob = new Blob(["1".repeat(1e3)]);
    const encryptedBlob = await encryptBlobToBlob(blob, secret);
    console.log("enrypted blob size", encryptedBlob.size);
    const decryptedBlob = await decryptBlobToBlob(encryptedBlob, secret);
    console.log("decryptedBlob", decryptedBlob);
    console.log(await decryptedBlob.text());
}
main();
```